# How do I translate a text from iso-8859-1 to UTF-8 in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding

How do I translate a text from iso-8859-1 to UTF-8 in Java.

Example: Á (iso-8859-1) to Á (UTF-8).

In other words, change the unicode, so that the same printed character remains.

Comment: It's unclear what your _text_ is in this case. Is it just a `String`? Is it the contents of a file? Is it a `byte[]`?

Comment: I got a file that claims to have a UTF8 encoding, but I don't think it's true, because when I try to remove accent, it doesn't work. And also when I see its decimal, "(int) letter", it returns the value 131066, when I turn to return 386 (which would be correct in UTF-8). My first job is to find out what the true encoding of this file is, and then perform its conversion.

Answer (score 2):

`String` instances **are text**, they do not have an encoding and therefore your question is nonsense.

However, bytes can represent text, but only if they are encoded with some encoding.

Thus, perhaps you meant: I have a sack of bytes; they represent text in ISO-8859-1 charset encoding. I would like to transform this sack of bytes into a different sack of bytes such that turning that second sack of bytes into a string by way of applying UTF-8 encoding turns into the same text.

This is how you would do this:

```
String test = "Á";
byte[] inIso88591 = test.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
assert inIso88591.length == 1;
String backToString = new String(inIso88591, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
assert test.equals(backToString);
byte[] asUtf8 = backToString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
assert asUtf8.length == 2;
String backYetAgain = new String(asUtf8, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
assert backYetAgain.equals(test);
```